# Move a sentence 20px every 3 seconds with setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I'm trying to simply move a sentence 20px on the y-axis every 3 seconds by using `setInterval()`. My code will only move the sentence one time. What's going on?

```
var yAxis = 20;

setInterval(function() {
    $('.sentence').css('transform', 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0,' + yAxis + ')');
 }, 3000);
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brewpixels/fjgq7w0q/1/)

Comment: Do you know how to use a JavaScript debugger? If not, it's time to learn: here's a [guide to the Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools). Set a breakpoint on the line of code inside the `setInterval` and look at the value of `yAxis` each time. Does the value change or does it stay the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS directive you give is always the same - transform `.sentence` from its original position to 20points lower.

Use:

```
var yAxis=0;
setInterval(function() {
$('.sentence').css('transform', 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0,' + (yAxis+=20) + ')'); }, 3000);
```

instead

Comment: Close to what I want but the first animation appears to be 40px now instead of 20. After it moves 40px it repeats 20px down the y axis.

Comment: set yAxis to 0 first - I forgot += is pre-increment!

Comment: Perfect. Learned something. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `offset()` method to get offset of current element from left and from top. At first, get current offset from top and then override it with new value, which will be "oldOffset + 20px" in your case. Here is the working example:

```js
setInterval(function() {
    var el = $('.sentence');
    var currentOffset = el.offset();
    el.offset({ top: currentOffset.top + 20, left: currentOffset.left})
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="sentence">Text Text Text</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your transform does not add 20 to the existing Y. It simply sets the Y to 20. You need to store the state of the previous transformation then update that value before applying it to the next transform.

```js
let yAxis = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  yAxis += 20;
  $('.sentence').css('transform', 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0,' + yAxis + ')'); 
}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sentence">This is a sentence.</div>
```